# PHP - How to show another PDF's pages with ZipArchive()

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

My problem now, is that the second PDF and on, it not display, 'cause got a error. "Failed to load PDF Document". How can i solve this ?

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if(file_exists('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')+1).'.pdf') && is_file('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')+1).'.pdf')){
 $processo = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')+1);
 $file = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$processo.'.pdf';
 $filename = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$processo.'.pdf';
 header('Content-type: application/pdf');
 header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
 @readfile($file);
}else{
/////////////////////HERE IS THE PART WHEN IS A ZIP////////////////////////
///////*This part it's only to check if the folder extract exists*/////////
 function folder_exist($folder){ $path = realpath($folder); return ($path !== false AND is_dir($path)) ? $path : false; }
 chdir('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/');
 $folder = '/'.substr(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'p/')+2), 0, strpos(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'p/')+2), '/')).'/';
 if(FALSE !== ($path = folder_exist($folder))){
 /////*Here start the part where the code catch the PDF's and display*/////
  $pasta = substr(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'p/')+2), 0, strpos(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'p/')+2), '/'));
  $processo = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')+1);
  $file = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$pasta.'/'.$processo.'.pdf';
  $filename = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$pasta.'/'.$processo.'.pdf';
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  @readfile($file);
 }else{
  die('<h2 style="background-color:#FA5858"><center>Não foi encontrado a inicial do processo. Verifique se o mesmo encontra-se na pasta.</center></h2>');
 }
}
?>
```

This is my Javascript/HTML code that pass the PDF's names to PHP file to open them:

```
  setTimeout(function(){

   if(document.getElementById("content3").innerText == "PDF"){
      window.open("pdf.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value, '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800"); 
   }else{
      var QuantPDF = Number(document.getElementById("content3").innerText.slice(Number(document.getElementById("content3").innerText.lastIndexOf(','))+1, document.getElementById("content3").innerText.length));//Number(document.getElementById("content3").innerText.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
      var NomesPDFS = []; NomesPDFS = document.getElementById("content3").innerText.slice(3, document.getElementById("content3").innerText.length-2).split(',');
      if(QuantPDF > 1){
       for(var i = 0; i < QuantPDF; i++){
        window.open("pdf.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value+"/"+NomesPDFS[i], '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800");  
       }   
      }else{
       window.open("pdf.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value, '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800");    
      }
   }

  }, 1000);
```

Comment: You can't stream multiple pdf files to the browser.  You need to build a list of the files and link to them or find another way to present them to the user.

Comment: Even if i open multiple windows with this loop to display which one ?

I have this Javascript code, that receive the php value, to determine if is a pdf or a zip. But my php code, isn't open the others pdf

Comment: If users will unblock your site from allowing popups, it's certainly possible.  I wouldn't do that, but it seems possible.  You would have to call the PHP code with some front end JS code, then when the array of files comes back, you can loop and pop the windows one at a time.  Is there a reason you have to force the file into the browser instead of just letting them download it by clicking on it?

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ if(document.getElementById("content3").innerText == "PDF"){ window.open("pdf.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value, '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800"); ...` If it was a single pdf

Comment: `...}else{ var QuantPDF = document.getElementById("content3").innerText.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, ""); if(QuantPDF > 1){ for(var i = 0; i < QuantPDF; i++){ window.open("zip.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value, '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800"); } }else{ window.open("zip.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value, '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800"); } } }, 1000);` if it was a zip file

Comment: Can you add all that code into the example above so we have an example of how you'd like it to work with that JS code please?

Comment: You say download to display on something or the users download the pdf ? 'Cause the users doesn't need to download the pdf's

Comment: Ok, i will add on the rest of the code

Comment: Done. I updated my question

Comment: The window.open() in the for() loop, the url needs to be dynamic, otherwise, how will the PHP code know to provide the second or third PDF file?  It shows the same PDF because you're looping the PDF files that are in the ZIP file.  Each request just shows the first PDF in the zip.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a variable ($i) to the php script, so it can track where in the array of PDFs you are:

```
$.post("arquivo.php", {nprocesso: document.getElementById("processo").value}, function(data){   $( "#content3" ).html( data ); });

setTimeout(function(){

if(document.getElementById("content3").innerText == "PDF"){ //if the file is just a PDF, open it
  window.open("pdf.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value, '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800"); 
}else{ //if the file is a zip file, or many zip files, pass them to zip.php and unpack them
  var QuantPDF = document.getElementById("content3").innerText.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, "");
   if(QuantPDF > 1){  //there is more than one zip file
    for(var i = 0; i < QuantPDF; i++){ //loop the zip files
  window.open("zip.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value + "/" + $i, '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800");  
} 
   }else{ //Open just the one zip file
    window.open("zip.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value, '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800");    
   }
}

}, 1000);
```

Then remove the loop from your PHP file, since you're only getting one at a time, per popup:

```
<?php
$urlOfPHPFile = "http://somedomainthatsawesome.com/zip.php/somefilename.zip/2";
$arrURI = explode("/",$urlOfPHPFile);
$pdfPosition = array_pop($arrURI);
$zipFilename = array_pop($arrURI); //$processo
var_dump($pdfPosition);    //obviously comment this out when you're ready to test
echo "<br/>";    //obviously comment this out when you're ready to test
var_dump($zipFilename);    //obviously comment this out when you're ready to test
echo "<hr/>";    //obviously comment this out when you're ready to test
//....
$file = array($pdfPosition);
$stat = $za->statIndex( $pdfPosition );
$file[$pdfPosition] = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.basename($stat['name']).PHP_EOL;
$filename = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.basename($stat['name']).PHP_EOL;
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $file[$pdfPosition] . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file[$pdfPosition]));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@readfile($file[$pdfPosition]);
print_r( basename( strtoupper($stat['name']) ) . PHP_EOL . '<br>' );
?>
```

Comment: Have i to put this code `for(var i = 0; i < QuantPDF; i++){
  window.open("zip.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value + "/" + $i, '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800");  
}` on php ?  But this one isn't JavaScript ?

Comment: This is Javascript code.  It should stay in your HTML/JS file.  window.open is definitely Javascript :)

Comment: So why you said that i'm pass this code on a php file ?

Comment: Re-read it.  I said pass the VARIABLE, not the code.  I added some more javascript with documentation.  Please read the documentation and let me know if my assumptions are correct.

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't get at first what you said, but i understood later. I didn't do exactly the way that you explained, but i did something similar. Now, i got another error, the second pdf and later, they not read/open, show this: "Failed to load PDF document". But the first it display normally, and i check the code, it writing the path and the file name correctly. I will put the code that i built

Comment: Put a die(); right before the first header() and output the $file[$pdfPosition], basename($stat['name']) and all the other dynamic variables and see which one is incorrect.  That should give you your next thing to fix.  Also, insure that the document it's trying to retrieve is indeed there.